# Difference between `MapControllerRoute`, `MapDefaultControllerRoute`, and `MapControllers`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm upgrading .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.0 and I saw [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) I have to use `UseEndpoints`. However, at some pages I've seen it with either `MapControllerRoute`, `MapDefaultControllerRoute`, or `MapControllers`.

I checked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.iendpointroutebuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and I saw that `MapDefaultControllerRoute` is basically the same as `MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")`. But I don't understand the difference with `MapControllers`. What does this last function actually do? The documentation says: "Adds endpoints for controller actions to the IEndpointRouteBuilder without specifying any routes.", but I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: This might be helpful to you and others. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Builder/ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**MapControllerRoute**

Uses conventional routing (most often used in an MVC application), and sets up the URL route pattern. So you will have seen this in tutorials/documentation with something like this:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You could set this to whatever you wanted (within reason) and your routes would follow this pattern. The above pattern is basically `{{root_url}}/{{name_of_controller}}/{{name_of_action}}/{{optional_id}}` where, if controller and action are not supplied, it defaults to `home/index`.

**MapDefaultControllerRoute**
This is the above, but it shorthands the configuration of the default pattern that I displayed above.

**MapControllers**
This doesn't make any assumptions about routing and will rely on the user doing attribute routing (most commonly used in WebAPI controllers) to get requests to the right place.

N.B. It's entirely possible to use MapControllerRoute (and by proxy MapDefaultControllerRoute) along side attribute routing as well. If the user does not supply attributes, it will use the defined default pattern.

Comment: I'm inferring from your N.B. then that if you use `MapControllerRoute` then that is sufficient to do everything that `MapControllers` does (plus it specifies a fallback route for wherever no attributes are used)--that is, you don't need to call `MapControllers` _also_ if you called `MapControllerRoute`?

Comment: That's right, you do not use both (and I expect it would break if you did). If you expect to do attribute routing exclusively - usually with API controllers - then use `MapControllers`, otherwise use `MapControllerRoute` which will determine an endpoint's route from `controller_name/action_name` if an explicit, attribute-driven route is not provided, and also gives the benefit of a default route.

Comment: @Lozenger I found that it's just running the first method though with no attribute matches once it gets to the controller.

Answer (score 13):

`MapControllers` is used to map any attributes that may exist on the controllers, like, `[Route]`, `[HttpGet]`, etc.

From Microsoft:
Adds endpoints for controller actions to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder
without specifying any routes.
Explain:
This says it will map url to controller and action, you need specify your own route

Comment: this is wrong answer, if you just use MapControllerRoute, attribure routing is still working, tested in ASP.Net Core 3.1