# Routing is not working after migration to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, .net-core-3.1

I have done .NET Core migration from v2.1 to v3.1, and all seems to be fine except specific custom routing for action method.

This does not work:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("product/getallproduct")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

But this works:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getallproduct")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Now, this URL is not working. It returns 400 error.

After migration, my startup.cs having this code.

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Edited: if I remove `'product/'` from the route, then it works.

Comment: Hi , Does any `[Route("xx")]` on your controller? Can you provide your request URL?

Comment: Yes, I have controller level routes also. [Route("api/v1/{user}/mycontroller")]

Comment: Can you provide your request Url?

Comment: I try this Url `http://localhost:xxxx/api/v1/user/mycontroller/product/getallproduct` and success .

Comment: did you try with .net core 3.1? How is your startup.cs settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240746/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-user1298676).

Comment: you could lookup this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107064/difference-between-mapcontrollerroute-mapdefaultcontrollerroute-and-mapco